# OpenCL 1.1 C++ Bindings: Create cl::Event object from cl_event type in callback

Tags: c++, events, callback, opencl, wrapper

how can I create a cl::Event object from cl_event type in OpenCL event callback?
There's a cl::Event constructor in OpenCL 2.0 Reference:

```
Event (const cl_event &event, bool retainObject=false)
```

In OpenCL 1.1 there's only the inherited cl::Event member function

```
Wrapper(const Wrapper<cl_event> & rhs)
```

Here is my callback function:

```
void callback(cl_event ev, cl_int type, void *user_data)
{
    cl::Event event;
    event.Wrapper(cl::detail::Wrapper<cl_event>(ev));
}
```

And the compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void callback(cl_event, cl_int, void*)':
main.cpp:41:8: error: invalid use of 'cl::detail::Wrapper<_cl_event*>::Wrapper'
  event.Wrapper(cl::detail::Wrapper<cl_event>(ev));
        ^
main.cpp:41:48: error: no matching function for call to 'cl::detail::Wrapper<_cl_event*>::Wrapper(_cl_event*&)'
  event.Wrapper(cl::detail::Wrapper<cl_event>(ev));
                                                ^
main.cpp:41:48: note: candidates are:
In file included from main.cpp:23:0:
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:1106:5: note: cl::detail::Wrapper<T>::Wrapper(const cl::detail::Wrapper<T>&) [with T = _cl_event*]
     Wrapper(const Wrapper<cl_type>& rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:1106:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'cl_event {aka _cl_event*}' to 'const cl::detail::Wrapper<_cl_event*>&'
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:1099:5: note: cl::detail::Wrapper<T>::Wrapper() [with T = _cl_event*]
     Wrapper() : object_(NULL) { }
     ^
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:1099:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Thanks

Comment: There should be more inherited from `Wrapper` than what you see. In particular there is [`Wrapper (const cl_type &obj)`](https://kosobucki.pl/cl_doc/classcl_1_1Event.html#a2f024326bd9ac7ed35f8112151af0805) where `cl_type` is the template parameter passed into `Wrapper<T>`. By the way templating a base on the current class [is a common pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) to keep an eye out for.

Comment: Constructing the `Event` using `cl::Event event(ev);` should work just fine. Also, a big hint that something is wrong is that you're using a type from somebody else's [`detail` namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2082178/1020072).